# Cordova merges folder for plugins

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have read the documentation on how to use the "merges" folder for platform specific code, but the example given is for a common codebase with customisations for one platform only. My app uses the cordova-plugin-camera plugin. I have customisations for the android version and I have different customisations for the iOS version. How do I setup my folder structure?

Should I add a merges/android/assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-camera folder and a merges/ios/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-camera folder and **keep** the root/plugins/cordova-plugin-camera folder? Or should I **remove** the root/plugins/cordova-plugin-camera folder?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to do my plugin customisations with https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugman instead. I will import my customised plugin into the main project. This will remove the need for the merges folder.